# ExtJS 4: How to auto scale an image? (no clipping)

Tags: image, extjs, extjs4, scale, image-size

I have an Image Component in ExtJS which loads an image via URL like this:

```
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            src: 'http://www.asien-news.de/wp-content/uploads/new-york.jpg'
        },
```

The image is displayed at 100%. 200x200 px are shown and the rest is clipped. I didn't find any property to allow scaling.

What is the best way to achieve a resizing image in ExtJS?

Comment: If the image is inside a container or panel, it could be that the image is too large for its container. Possibly adjusting the size of whatever holds the image might make the difference.

Comment: No. The size of the image component if right. but the image is not scaled down to fit the 200x200px. Only the upper left area of the original image is displayed, but I want the image do fit the component size.

Comment: oh I just took a closer look to the generated DOM. The Image Component is not represented as a <img.../> tag but as a <div../> with background-image... That explains my "problem". Why the heck is it not a img-tag?

Comment: In the sencha docs it says "renders an image tag to the DOM with the configured src."

Comment: ok. that's strange. I'm using Sencha Touch, which should be the same as regular ExtJS (at least in this case...). But handling at as a DIV worked for me like this: imgDiv.setStyle({'background-image':'url('+imageURI+')'});

Answer (score 1):

You can use xtype:'image' , shrinkWrap:true

Please check with Ext js api http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Img-cfg-shrinkWrap

Answer (score 1):

A bit late...but I think this is kind of what you wish to have, I happened to use the image as a scaled background behind a panel instead of an image on top inside a panel, but the theory is the same:

```
//here is your view file
Ext.define('This_Is_A_Panel_On_Top_Of_A_Background_Container.view.MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport', //my root view port
    layout: {type: 'fit'},
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'container', //my background image
                    html: '<img id="imgEl" src="'+Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL+'">',
                    layout: {type: 'border'},
                    items: [{
                            xtype: 'panel', //my panel on top of background
                            region: 'center',
                            bodyCls: 'transparent',
                            title: 'My Panel'
                        }]
                }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Note that I didn't use image component, I used a container. `html: <img ...` and `bodyCls: transparent...` did the trick. You can change the image dynamically in a handler. Something like this:

```
//then say, in afterRender event, in your controller file
var imgEl = Ext.get('imgEl');
Ext.fly(imgEl).setStyle({
    backgroundImage: 'wallpaper.jpg',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}).show();
```